# How do I generate a range of specific numbers given mean?

Tags: r

Given a vector of specified values, for example:

```
x = c(4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0)
```

I would like to create a new vector of any length comprised only of values in x sampled randomly, that will result in the combined mean of `3.15`. I have tried using the `rnorm()` function but however, I can only generate random numbers that equate to the mean of `3.15` and not the specified values I wanted. Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: what is the logic for those specific values?

Comment: I think Corey is looking for a vector of numbers, drawn from the set {4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0}, with the desired mean. Obviously @dww's answer gives 2.5, not 3.15.

Comment: Do you need a certain number of values? At low lengths, you can't be sure a set of randomly generated numbers will have a specific mean (they are, after all, random). This will become less of a problem as the number of random numbers grows bigger. Generally speaking, at 500 or so you'll be pretty damn close to 3.5 if you set your random numbers to revolve around that.

Comment: For reference, in most US schools, the values provided are the grade-point weightings of the letter grades (A = 4.0, A- = 3.7, and so on)

Comment: The output is similar to what I would get from rnorm() where I can generate n numbers of values equal to the mean. I am wondering if there's a way to generate n number of specified values in this case its 4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0. I am plenning to generate at least 20 values.

Comment: As @iod mentioned, no sampling scheme (even `rnorm`) will guarantee that the sample mean is a certain value. Do you want your sample mean to be exactly 3.15 or approximately 3.15?

Comment: it doesn't have to be exactly 3.15, but as close as possible! and nope, any number of each value could occur as long as the mean equates to approximately 3.15.

Comment: How close you are depends on your sample size! One solution (maybe not the one you want) is to draw from {3.0, 3.3} with equal probability: `sample(c(3.0, 3.3), size = 100, replace = TRUE)` (replace 100 with your desired sample size)

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question in line with the info from OP in comments.  If I got it wrong, then OP please roll back the change

Comment: Another approach would be to simply have r run a few tens of thousands of simulations of the sampling, and then filter the results for those with the desired means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my brute force method:

```
samp315<-function(n=20, desmean=3.15, distance=0.001) { # create a function with default n=20 and range 3.149-3.151
  x<- c(4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0)
  samp<-0 # reset samp to 0
  i<-0 # reset my counter to zero
  while (!between(mean(samp),desmean-distance,desmean+distance) & i<1000000) {  # the following will run continuously until a sample (samp) with a mean that falls within the specified range is found, OR until 1 million attempts have been made
    samp<-sample(x,n,replace=TRUE) # try to generate a sample of n times from the list of values (x)
    i=i+1 # add to counter towards 1 million
   }
  ifelse(i<1000000,samp,warning("Couldn't find an appropriate sample, please select a lower n, a desired mean closer to 2.5, or a greater distance"))  # if the while loop ended because the counter reached a million, exit with an error, otherwise, return the contents of samp.
 }
```

Now, every time you do `samp315()`:

```
eg<-samp315()
mean(eg)
[1] 3.15
eg
[1] 3.0 3.7 3.0 3.7 3.3 3.7 3.3 3.3 4.0 1.0 1.7 3.0 2.0 4.0 3.7 3.7 2.3 3.3 4.0 3.3
```

If you want a sample of different length, just place whatever number you wish inside `samp315()`. The larger the number, however, the longer it will take to find a sample that will get your desired mean.

You can also change your desired mean by setting `desmean`, and play around with the range by changing `distance` to whatever the distance (+/-) from your desired mean can be. The default is n=20, with the range from 3.149 to 3.151.

To avoid an infinite loop for highly unlikely combinations of n and range, I set a maximum of 1m samples, after which the function quits with a warning.

Comment: This is amazing thank you so much, I would also appreciate it if you could break down your approach logically!

Comment: I added comments in the answer to explain what each line does. Basically, like I said at the start, it's a brute force method that relies on the fact that if you simulate a sampling long enough, eventually you'll get any possible combination. So I just tell it to sample infinitely (or at least 1 million times), and only stop if the mean of the sample selected falls within a given range.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your question is that there are an infinite number of ways to sample from

```
x = c(4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0)
```

to get a mean of roughly `3.15`, you just have a specify a probability for each value.

Doing

```
n = 20
sample(x, n, replace = TRUE)
```

assumes each value is equally likely and you would get a mean close to `2.5`. But if you re-weight the probabilities, you can get closer to what you want. One way of doing this might be

```
p = 1/(x - 3.15)^2    # or try p = 1/abs(x - 3.15)
sample(x, n, replace = TRUE, prob = p)
```

where `p` weights values closer to `3.15` higher so these are more likely to be accepted. It isn't perfect (meaning the true expected value is something like `3.12` and most values are just `2.7`, `3.0` and `3.3`), but then again there isn't a single solution.

Comment: I had already tried this method but did not post an answer, because when I test it for large n, it does not give quite the correct mean. same problem with both the `^2` and `abs` versions.  I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work

Comment: @dww, It's because of the asymmetry around `3.15` and insisting on each value having non-zero probability of being selected. If you wanted to have a true mean of `3.15`, you might have to choose to values for `p` manually (there are an infinite number of choices). Using `^2` or `abs` was meant to act more like a starting point or an approximation.

Comment: Notice that `3.15 = (3.3 + 3)/2` so that is one solution. You can just repeat an equal number of 3's and 3.3's to get other combinations. 
`mean(c(rep(3.3,42), rep(3,42)))  = 3.15`

But also `(2.3+4)/2 = 3.15` so you can also add in any number of these pairs.
`mean(c(rep(3.3,42), rep(3,42), rep(2.3, 1066), rep(4,1066))) = 3.15`

Answer (score 1):

As @mickey pointed out, we can weight the probability of each item according to how far it is from the mean. However, that does not quite work, because there are more elements in x lower than than the desired mean, which skews the sampling towards them.  We can account for this by adjusting the probabilites relative to how many elements are higher or lower than the desire mean:

```
x = c(4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0)
n = 100000
xbar=3.15

xhi = x[which(x>xbar)]
xlo = x[which(x<xbar)]
probhi = 1/(xhi-xbar)
problo = 1/(xbar-xlo)

probhi = probhi * length(problo) / length(probhi)

n=1e5
set.seed(1)
y = sample(x, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(probhi,problo))
mean(y)
# [1] 3.150216
```

Comment: But this leaves the problem of not actually getting the desired mean with lower samples. We can combine this solution with my brute force solution to improve the efficiency, while still ensuring the the resulting sample provides the desired mean.