# Why does my function only sometimes work?

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
samp315<-function(n=30, desmean=86, distance=3.4995) { 
  x = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.1)
  samp<-0
  while (!between(mean(samp),desmean-distance,desmean+distance)) samp<-sample(x,n,replace=TRUE)
  samp
}
percent <- samp315()
```

so pretty much I want to generate 30 numbers within 0-100 that has a mean of 86+/-3.4995, however whenever I run the last line it will load forever or when I am lucky it will genrate a list of desired results. Any idea on how i could change the function to improve its functionality?

Comment: All it depends on the randomization of your numbers in `sample()`. Some may take a while and others not to reach `while` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Parfait in the comments, you're using a randomization strategy that gives a low probability of providing the condition you're interested in. Did no other answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216065/how-do-i-generate-a-range-of-specific-numbers-given-mean?answertab=votes#tab-top) help you out?

Some other possible strategies for you to try out.

```
n = 30

# Using truncated normal
library(truncnorm)
x = round(rtruncnorm(n, a = -0.0495, b = 100.0495, mean = 85, sd = 3.5*2), 1)

# Using beta
sig = 3
x = round(100*rbeta(n, (0.85)*sig, (1-0.85)*sig), 1)
```

The `round(..., 1)` is meant to align with your vector `x`. These methods would both have very few values away from 85. It's a trade-off you have to consider. If you want to have a mean in 85 +/- 3.5, then you can't too many values below 10, for example. So you have to lower the probability of such values being selected. Using your function, when it is completed, you'll probably find that values closer to 85 are more represented.